# Elixir spawn processes without self recursion in anonymous function

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir

I am pretty new to elixir and functional programming in general, and I was wondering in the specific example below how can I add 'nodes' in the currently empty list in the 3rd parameter of the spawn/3 function.

```
  def create(n) do
    nodes = Enum.map(1..n, fn(_) -> spawn(Node, :begin, []) end)
  end
```

For example what I am trying to do is similar to this:

```
  def create(n) do
    nodes = Enum.map(1..n, fn(_) -> spawn(Node, :begin, [nodes]) end)
  end
```

I have tried piping and pre declared nodes but as processes, they are already spawn and the begin function is already triggered following the other ways.

What I am trying to do and needs nodes for is for the class Node as follows

```
defmodule Node do
  def begin(nodes) do
    # do stuff with nodes here
  end
end
```

Comment: You can't do it like this because `nodes` will be set after the `Enum.map` is complete. You can't pass the PID of a process which hasn't been created yet. What are you trying to do here? There might be a better way.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to have a
`defmodule Node do
  def begin(nodes) do
    # do stuff with nodes
  end
end
`

Comment: the formatting in my previous code is very bad, it should be vertical

Comment: Node.spawn_link may be the function you are looking for. It starts a process in a given node.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I believe you'll need to create the nodes first.

```
Enum.map(1..n, fn ... create node here ... end)
```

Then pipe them to a map operation that will evaluate your nodes using the `Node.begin` function.

```
Enum.map(nodes, &Node.begin/1)
```

If `Node.begin` is some expensive( heavy workload ) operation you could take advantage of creating async Tasks to handle the heavy workload in separate processes.

```
nodes
|> Enum.map(&(Task.async(fn -> Node.begin(&1) end))) 
|> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
```

**FYI: `&Node.begin/1` passes the `Node.begin` function to the callback of `Enum.map`. The `&(...)` part inside of the map call is a shorthand anonymous function.**

Here's the final code:

```
# If Node.begin is a heavy operation
def create(n) do
  Enum.map(1..n, fn -> ... create nodes here ... end)
  |> Enum.map(&Node.begin/1)
end
```

---

```
# If Node.begin will take some muscle to complete
def create(n) do
  Enum.map(1..n, fn -> ... create nodes here ... end)
  |> Enum.map(&(Task.async(fn -> Node.begin(&1) end)))
  |> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
end
```